# What is the use of ConnectionStrings__AzureWebJobsStorage?

Tags: azure, function

After the deployment of an azure function I stumbled over the configuration setting
ConnectionStrings__AzureWebJobsStorage. It seems to have been auto deployed and has exactly the same value as AzureWebJobsStorage. I have read about AzureWebJobsStorage, but what is the use of ConnectionStrings__AzureWebJobsStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently started learning about .Net core and discovered that `__` in configuration settings is a way to represent JSON hierarchy. So essentially `ConnectionStrings__AzureWebJobsStorage` would look something like:

```
"ConnectionString": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "some-connection-string-value"
}
```

This would allow you to read the connection string using [`GetConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) extension method.

So essentially, both of them serve the same purpose i.e. give you the ability to read the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string. The difference would be how you would like to read them.

Answer (score 1):

It won't add anything additional unless you have added or change when it ask to specify the values or proceed with the same while publishing. Check how you deployed/Published.